# Converting a PowerShell Post Command to Python Post API Call

Tags: python, powershell, api

I am trying to connect to a 3rd party API (Secunia)

The below POST code works perfectly in Power Shell -

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Post -Body $Body -WebSession $global:Session
```

$URL is a string as 
http://url_name/csi/api/?uid=****&action=hosts&which=get_host_scan_results

$Body is a string as 
device_id=1182&dir=ASC&eol=true&insecure=true&patched=true&start=165&limit=11

$global:Session is a string as 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession

I try to convert this API call in Python as -

```
deviceid = '1182'
directory ='ASC'
boolean = True

parameters = {
    'device_id': deviceid,
    'dir': directory,
    'eol':boolean,
    'insecure':boolean,
    'patched':boolean,
    'start':165,
    'limit':11
}

url_hostscanstatus = 'urlname/csi/api/?uid='+uid+'&action=csi_completed_scans&which=overview/'
response_hostscanstatus = requests.get(url_hostscanstatus,data=json.dumps(parameters))
```

But when i run this command, i get 400 error code.

Would appreciate any help to fix this issue ?

Comment: You're trying to do a `get` request, but your question asks about `post`. Try `requests.post(url_hostscanstatus…)`

Comment: That was a typo. I tried running requests.post

Comment: Reply i get is - <bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>
400
b''

Comment: can you try it firts with using postman? and later convert it in python script?

Comment: I don't think you need to do `json.dumps(parameters)`, pretty sure you can just pass in a `dict` i.e. `data=parameters`.